# Does Latin have minced oath interjections?

Tags: vulgar-latin, interjection

Does Latin have [minced oath](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/minced_oath) interjections analogous to English's *Jeez* (< *Jesus*), *Gosh* (< *God*), *gee whiz* (< *geewhillikins* < *Jerusalem*)?

<sup>cf. Christianity StackExchange question "[Do Catholics consider saying 'Jeez(e)!' to be a violation of the Second Commandment?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/41737/1787)"</sup>

Comment: The term you're looking for is *minced oath*. ("Gee whiz" and its variants are also from Jesus, not Jerusalem.)

Comment: @Cairnarvon Thank you. That term is more precise.

Answer (score 6):

In the same sense? No. Graeco-Roman religion didn't have the same taboo against uttering the name of a deity that Christians in modern Europe have, so they didn't develop minced oaths properly.

In fact, some phrases containing gods' names were so common, that they ended up looking like elliptical phrases. The two off the top of my head are [*mehercle*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mehercule#Latin) and [*edepol*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/edepol). I'll quote Wiktionary, since they're accessible:

*Mehercle*

> From an ellipsis of ita mē Herculēs amet/iuvet or the like.

While *mehercule* is the more common form, you'll also see *mehercle* and even *mercle* (in Cato and Cicero). [See the comments on doubts about the origin.]

*Edepol*:

> From ē (“by”) +‎ deus (“god”) +‎ Pollux.

This was most common in the comedies of Plautus and Terence, but it also shows up later, including in Cicero.

Comment: Reading *mehercle* as an ellipsis always felt like folk etymology to me, especially since the supposed full phrase is completely unattested. I'm inclined to compare it to Greek [μά](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%CE%BC%CE%AC#Ancient_Greek), either as a loan (given that it's only ever used with a Greek god; μὰ Ἡρακλέα could be borrowed wholesale) or a true cognate.

Comment: @Cairnarvon Yeah, I have my doubts, too. That's why I defaulted to just quoting Wiktionary. At least it fits for the purpose of the question (because of *mercle*). (Well, at least what the OP thought it was --- they're probably not minced oaths, but more in line with something like "good-bye").

Comment: I'm sure the "Graeco-Roman religion" didn't tolerate disrespecting their gods (blasphemy), else why did they martyr Christians?

Comment: @Geremia This is drastically oversimplifying things, but to a certain extent the Roman religion and the Roman state were one and the same, so the Christians saying "hey join us and reject the old ways" were undermining the state. But poking fun at Jupiter or using his name in jest wasn't a problem.

Comment: @Geremia The ancient Greeks and Romans didn't hold such beliefs (which they deemed superstitions) that merely saying a name was blasphemy. That came later from outsiders.

Comment: @cmw "merely saying a name" of a god wouldn't constitute blasphemy. Blasphemy would be using the name in a disrespectful or vulgar way.

Comment: @Geremia I think you're taking a modern stance [at odds with antiquity](https://www.haaretz.com/archaeology/2018-10-10/ty-article-magazine/.premium/we-shouldnt-take-gods-name-in-vain-but-what-is-it/). The Greeks and Romans put on irreverent comedies and wrote parodies about the gods all the time.

Comment: @cmw If that's the case, then it seems minced oaths wouldn't exist among the pagan Romans. What about among the Christian Romans?